# Use general file-base from server, unless the file exist locally

Tags: php, apache, file, server

We've build a CRM website were people can place reservations.

We're about to have more customers for this system, which means maintanance is something to think about a bit differently, we don't want to update 15+ sites for every (tiny) update we create.

**I'm looking for a system which works like this:**

Try to open file `/file.txt` (e.g.: `file_get_contents("/file.txt")` ):

- If the file exist in the directory of userA, return this file
  - eg: `/home/usera/wwwroot/domainname.ext/file.txt`
- If it doesn't: Return file from a general specified location on the server
  - eg: now return: `/home/GENERAL_POOL/file.txt` ( like a virtual link / alias / shortcut)

We want this because this there will be a lot more users and I only want to update one file (leaving versions aside). If I add a feature, they should all have it, because they all work on the same code.
The local files are mainly templates and stylesheets, but it could be an exception PHP file.

**Small example:**

- Let's say there is a function to `saveOrder()` in `/saveOrder.php`. I want all our clients to use that, so I don't create that file locally so they all take it from the general pool.
  Now we've fixed a bug in `/saveOrder.php` and ***boom*** all users have the fix (yes, I'm also aware of the possible dangers this brings).
- I do want a custom style for this user, so `/style.css` is placed locally and thus used instead of the file in the general pool.

**Things which might be handy to know:**

- We're working with an up-to-date apache server
- This server is dedicated to this type of system/website
- We're free to do with it whatever we want.

How can we aproach this? Does such a system exist and if so, what's it called? If not, how can we create this. I'm looking for the most effecient method, messing with `.htaccess` files isn't prefered.
Also, if there's a way to create versions, that would be great

*If more info is needed to answer this question, please let me know.*

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking, but since you mention `apache`, you could test if the asked file exist in clientA directory, and fallback to you "general pool".  This would make use of `ProxyPassMatch `  or `RewriteCond` (to test availability) and `RewriteRule` (to fallback)

Comment: Just a simple rewrite rule should be able to do this; or perhaps a bunch of symbolic links that can be replaced by normal files.

Comment: Well, apart from the fact that htaccess won't allow userA to access files on the server of another user. It has to be a bit more thorough. PHP functions should not be altered, they should treat everything as if it were local (like `file_exists()`)

Comment: Just so I understand well. You are providing a CRM to your clients. They can customize the appearance, or the code, and to do so, they have to modify the core files of your product. Is that right ? Why don't you take a plugin / theme based approach where the software itself is left untouched ?

Comment: No, we change the style per client ourselfes. We want 1 pile of files which all sites use (so no copies of files), a bit like a virtual link. But with a `first-check-if-file-exists-locally`. If you know how to clarify the question, please tell me so I can improve my topic :)

Comment: Rephrazed my question, hope it's more clear now

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://unionfs.filesystems.org/ which seems like a low-level file-system based solution for your need. Basically, your CRM would be merged with empty directories, with a copy-on-write behaviour for modified files on each client's merged mounted file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for [unionfs-fuse](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/unionfs-fuse.8.html).

Let's say your CMS is stored in `/home/GENERAL_POOL/`.
For each of your customers, you have a directory, initially empty, named `/home/usera/files/`.
You want his files to be served from `/home/usera/wwwroot/domainname.ext/`.

Using unionfs-fuse, you can use the following command for each of your customers:

```
$ unionfs-fuse -o cow \
             /home/usera/files=RW:/home/GENERAL_POOL=RO \
             /home/usera/wwwroot/domainname.ext
```

This command merges `/home/usera/files` and `/home/GENERAL_POOL` into `/home/usera/wwwroot/domainname.ext`.

While more fuse options can be given, this example illustrates the most important ones.
`-o cow` enables copy on write, so when a file in `/home/usera/wwwroot/domainname.ext` is modified, it is written in the top-level read-write directory `/home/usera/files`.
Since `/home/GENERAL_POOL` is read-only, it will never be modified by this mount point, but any update you make in the original directory will be automatically reflected for all clients.

When a file is read, the first directory takes precedence, here `/home/usera/files`. If not found in that directory, it will be searched in `/home/GENERAL_POOL`.

Comment: I've been testing a bit with this, looks very promising! I believe this is exactly what we're looking for. I'm going to work with this a bit more and come back later to mark as solution.

Comment: @Martijn since my knowledge of this program is pretty theorical, improvements to this answer from your practical experience are much welcome.

Comment: At this point im researching AUFS aswell. It looks like that's a fork of unionfs, but accoring to the internet, more stable. To bad all I can find about this is 2007 stuff, nothing modern.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is not a consideration now, you might want to switch to a service such as S3 in the future. With this in mind it might be worthwhile to use a library such as [Flysystem](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QjBAwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fflysystem.thephpleague.com%2F&ei=A7-KVaz9GMO3sQHNwqf4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGuggd1EmduWLmFZOjTPpmxC1bJWg&bvm=bv.96339352,d.bGg) for abstracting away the filesystem. This will help you with your current setup as well. Have a look at the Caching-section, especially Adapter caching.

Comment: I find the website a little scarce with information, but I might check it out another time :)

Comment: There is another similar library called Gaufrette. You might want to look into that as well.